# Similar Addresses are overlapping on each other in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

I'm using Google Maps in my academic project,I've provided map for users to enter their address,Up-to that its working fine.On home page I need to display map,on map I've to show users addresses as markers(red dots).

[image: Markers are overlapped on each other on Google Maps]
Suppose user#1 have H.NO:45-6-3,Abids,Hyderabad and user#2 have H.No:8-9-54,Abids,Hyderabad.These two addresses are near to each other they are overlapping.I need to display two individual markers on map.What I should do ? I'm using OpenLayers map,I don't want to use clusters.

Comment: You have to decide, how you want to display a markers on the map (in such a situation). After that you can write your Strategy or style map that implement your wishes.